# Removing noise and detecting groups of rastercells that forms possible features in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, noise

This is a raster image containing cells with values ranging from 0 to 10. You can see rastercells forming lines, which illustrates agricultural ditches, and more groups of red cells within the fields, showing microdepressions within the field. There is also some random noise cells.
The goal is to eliminate noise and to detect the groups of cells that might show the microdepressions.

[image: example of raster image]

I have already tried the majority filter and I have also tried to convert the image to a binarumap (cell = 0 or cell = 1) and than used focal statistics to detect the noise (clustering pixels). But this did not really work.

How do I detect the microdepressions or at least eliminate the noise?

Comment: You can do Shrink, Expand or simply region group and pick groups that are large enough in your opinion.  Use binary raster 1, nodata.